# remove pages from google dynamic url - robots.txt

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt, google-search, google-search-console, search-engine-bots

I have a few links on google that are **domain.com/results.php?name=a&address=b**

The results page/parameters has now been renamed and I need to remove the existing links on google etc.

*I tried*

**User-agent: *
Disallow: /results.php**

in robots.txt and then on google webmaster added the url to be removed:

**domain.com/results.php**

it says it was removed successfully, however when I look at google an type domain.com - the existing urls with parameters are all still there.

What am I doing wrong? There are quite a few links so I need a way to deal with all of them at once instead of one by one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could put a page at results.php, and just get it to return a 301 redirect back your home page.

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.Your-Website.com"); 
?>
```

As Google recrawls your site, the old pages will disappear. You may find this works faster than just having removed the old page.