# Remove dynamically generated url from google search

Tags: html, asp.net, search, seo

I have a page in my website, It takes two parameters in query string.
I don't want to show this page on google search. I put meta tag as below:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

But It still shows results as Cached, I tried google webmaster to remove the url's. It removes requested url but not stopping index the url and I am getting the url with some other parameter value. I don't want to show this page on search completely. 
I looked at [remove pages from google dynamic url - robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069861/remove-pages-from-google-dynamic-url-robots-txt) 
But I am not getting my answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue. After you made all the recommended steps, i.e. added 'noindex' meta tag, disallowed it in robots.txt and removed from search in Webmaster Tools it may take a couple of weeks until the page completely disappears from search results. It's Google.

So, an only way to prevent the page from visiting is catch the request on server and redirect.